# How to do multi threading using KafkaListener with multiple pods?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Please help. We have 3 partitions and 3 instances(pods) running in prod. I assume each consumer instance would pick 1 message (if setConcurrency(1)) from each partition. We are using KafkaListener as mentioned below:

**Question**:

1. Method **processMatch(matchInfo)** is slow so i would like to do multi threading here. What is the best approach?
2. If i **setConcurrency(3)**, is that mean each consumer instance would create 3 consumer thread and would pick 3 messages at a time from each partition, meaning three consumer threads say 1,2,3 from instance 1 would pick 3 message from partition 0 and similarly consumer thread 1,2,3 from instance 2 would pick 3 message from partition 1 and consumer thread 1,2,3 from instance 3 would pick 3 message from partition 2. Is my understanding correct?
3. How are these work together or if there is any relation in them - setConcurrency() and max.poll.records and setBatchListener(true)?

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "matching.matches.internal", groupId = "matching", containerFactory = "matchInfoKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void matchInfoKafkaConsumer(ConsumerRecord<String, MatchInfo> recordFromKafka, Acknowledgment ack) {

        log.info("MatchInfoConsumer - key(matchId): {}, partition: {}", recordFromKafka.key(), recordFromKafka.partition());
        MatchInfo matchInfo = recordFromKafka.value();
        processMatch(matchInfo); 
        ack.acknowledge();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No; for 3 instances with concurrency = 3, you would need 9 partitions, otherwise you would have 6 idle consumers.

It is not good practice to multi-thread process records from a single partition because Kafka only maintains a "last committed offset".

However, there is a new listener container property `asyncAcks` which means that if you multi-thread a listener, any out of order commits will be deferred.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#ooo-commits

However, it is much better to increase the partitions if you wish to increase concurrency.